# How to implement Aggregation in Camel Seda

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to aggregate thread processing data from a Seda queue in camel?

Can anyone suggest how it can be done?

Comment: Have you looked at the Aggregate EIP?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the camel route like this, and you can find more example [here](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html)

```
from("seda:header").setHeader("visited", constant(true)).aggregate(header("cheese")).to("mock:result");
```